# Sharing an intent with text and an image produces error in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to share an intent with text and an image with other Android apps but I can't seem to get it to work.  I've been following this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html, but it doesn't seem to work or I'm doing something wrong.

This is the code I am using to create this intent:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=game.bounce");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://game.bounce/"+R.mipmap.logo));
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share using:"));
```

When I go to run my intent it throws this error:

```
W/Bundle﹕ Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$StringUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

In particular I'm trying to share this with Facebook and the Facebook app also produces this error:

```
Please attach photos or a single video.
```

I've been speculating this line might be producing the error:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://game.bounce/"+R.mipmap.logo));
```

But I've also tried this:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("https://path.to.my.image));
```

and that doesn't work

Anybody with tips on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You chose action type "Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)" Witch means it will take an list of things to send instead of single item.

Use array list of type URI

```
ArrayList<Uri> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpList.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://game.bounce/"+R.mipmap.logo);
```

And then suply it to extra stream

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, tmpList );
```

Comment: I tried that before and I tried it again and I still get an error.  This is the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable.  It also says in the documentation the Uri class implements Parcelable

Comment: I tested that exactly code on my machine and it work

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's the particular app I'm trying to share with and the device I'm using.  I'm using a Google Nexus 4 and I'm trying to share with the Facebook and Gmail apps.  What device and apps did you use when you got yours working?

Comment: Xperia z1c with messaging app

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$StringUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

You intent accept an ArrayList Object but you give him an Uri Object.

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(imageUri1); // Add your image URIs here
```